# Repeated iterations of trisection (Cantor sets)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to build intuition for Cantor sets by doing repeated trisections (and removing the central open interval). Below is one trisection.

$$[x,y]\to\left[x,x+\frac{y-x}{3}\right]\cup\left[y-\frac{y-x}{3},y\right]$$

In the above trisection, the central interval $\left(x+\frac{y-x}{3},y-\frac{y-x}{3}\right)$ is removed.

Repeated applications trisect each segment created by the prior trisection. Is there a general formula for $n$ trisections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you start from $[0,1]$ so the first trisection removes the interval $(\frac13,\frac23)$ then the way I think about it is that $n$th step of trisections (there are $2^{n-1}$ of them) removes those real numbers which when written in ternary (i.e. base $3$) have a $1$ in the $n$th position but not in earlier positions and which are not of the form $\frac{m}{3^n}$ for some integer $m$.

So for example:

- the first trisections removes ternary numbers of the form $0.1\ldots$
- the second set of trisections removes ternary numbers of the form $0.01\ldots$ and $0.21\ldots$
- the third set of trisections removes ternary numbers of the form $0.001\ldots$, $0.021\ldots$, $0.201\ldots$, and $0.221\ldots$

apart from numbers where $\ldots$ represents recurring $0$s or recurring $2$s.

Comment: I have no idea why this answer has two downvotes.  It is a perfectly valid and mathematically correct answer.  If it's not what someone was looking for, that's not the fault of the answer but rather one's lack of understanding.

Comment: It also seems valid to me.